# Unity local avoidance in user created world

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity3D for a networked multiplayer online game where I have a very large complex 3D terrain scene like a forest, with trees, cliff, hills, mountains, bounders, etc.

Players can also build structures sort of like minecraft, and put them anywhere in the scene, or even move them around anytime.

Aside from the human controlled players, there are automated AI players and objects like animals roaming around the scene following a path.

The problem is how to make these automated AI players and animals, able to navigate around the static and dynamic player created structures, because the path they follow can easily get blocked by player created structures, or even by other players and other AI objects, cliffs etc. So they have to find away around them or get themselves back on track if they tumble down off a high cliff for example.

So I made a navMesh and used NavAgents, but that just takes care of the static, non moving objects, but how do I make the AI players navigate around each other and also the dynamic structures created by the players which can number in the hundreds?

I thought of adding a NavMeshObstacle to everything, but this would result in it being attached to hundreds of objects since the user created structures are built using little pieces like blocks or little tiles to create a larger object.

Here are my questions:

1. Would attaching a NavMeshObstacle to hundreds of little objects slow down the game?
2. Is there another way to navigate of dynamic objects other than using NavMeshObstable without slowing down the networked game?

Thanks

Comment: for a direct answer on your 2 questions: 1 Fork your project and try/test if it will really be a performance issue; 2: Yes, a lot of ways that will depending on the characteristics of your game. If your build are based on blocks just like minecraft, instead of place NavMeshObstacle on each block you can implement a building system with a build status, for example, when build is complete you calculate the bounds and generates a hidden mesh to apply NavMeshObstacle and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation for NavMeshObstacle, one could reasonably assume that if carving (an obstacle "carving" a piece out of the nav mesh) is disabled, obstacles will only affect agent performance when they are in the agent's way. They won't affect pathfinding. The agent will just go around them when it's close. Note that this will not work for you if there are so many dynamic obstacles that the agents need a very different path. You can also set them to re-carve a piece out of the nav mesh only when they've moved a certain amount. You should test the performance, but that sounds like it might work well for you.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/NavMeshObstacle.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to spend much time on making your own "sensor and navigation" system extending unity's navigation then I think your way is through NavMeshObstacles. If you build your obstacles with blocks like minecraft to avoid add NavMeshObstacle on each block you have a huge range of choices on how to limit/approach on your building system.

There is also good AI systems free as [RAIN](http://rivaltheory.com/rain/), for example, that implements some extensible and consistent way to do what you want, take a look on unity market if anything there fits your needs.